# Deserializing an object to xml, its properties are not set

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to communicate with a webservice, and I constructed a request that I send to the server. However, the webservice doesn't get all the properties that I set.

The operation in the wsdl is this:

```
    <operation name="GetCommunityPeopleIds">
      <soap:operation soapAction="GetCommunityPeopleIds" style="document" />
      <xrd:version>v1</xrd:version>
      <input>
        <soap:body parts="body" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="consumer" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="producer" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="userId" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="id" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="service" use="literal" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body parts="body" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="consumer" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="producer" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="userId" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="id" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:standardheader" part="service" use="literal" />
      </output>
    </operation>
```

The two messages associated are:

```
  <message name="GetCommunityPeopleIds">
    <part name="body" element="tns:GetCommunityPeopleIds" />
  </message>
  <message name="GetCommunityPeopleIdsResponse">
    <part name="body" element="tns:GetCommunityPeopleIdsResponse" />
  </message>
```

and these are the elements:

```
      <element name="GetCommunityPeopleIds">
        <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element name="request" type="tns:communityPeopleIdsRequest" />
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
      </element>
      <element name="GetCommunityPeopleIdsResponse">
        <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element name="faultCode" type="xrd:faultCode" nillable="true" />
            <element name="faultString" type="xrd:faultString" nillable="true" />
            <element name="request" type="tns:communityPeopleIdsRequest" />
            <element name="response">
              <complexType>
                <sequence>
                  <element minOccurs="0" name="PeopleIds" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPersonIds" />
                  <element minOccurs="0" name="TotalCount" type="int" />
                </sequence>
              </complexType>
            </element>
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
      </element>
```

The referred type `communityPeopleIdsRequest` is defined as follows:

```
      <complexType name="communityPeopleIdsRequest">
        <sequence>
          <element name="requestBody">
            <complexType>
              <sequence>
                <element minOccurs="0" name="Count" type="int" />
                <element minOccurs="0" name="ModifiedBefore" type="dateTime" />
                <element minOccurs="0" name="ModifiedSince" type="dateTime" />
                <element minOccurs="0" name="SortDescriptions" type="tns:ArrayOfSortDescription" />
                <element minOccurs="0" name="StartIndex" type="int" />
              </sequence>
            </complexType>
          </element>
          <element name="requestHeader">
            <complexType>
              <sequence>
                <element name="token" type="string">
                  <annotation>
                    <appinfo>
                      <xrd:title xml:lang="en">a fedAuth token</xrd:title>
                    </appinfo>
                  </annotation>
                </element>
              </sequence>
            </complexType>
          </element>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
```

My problem is that as I have referenced this webservice and am invoking it from a vb.net forms application; when I do, the webservice owner tells me that when I call the webservice, my properties are not getting passed to the webservice - all the attributes of the requestBody are empty.

Here is my code for constructing the request to the webservice, where actually do set the dates values in the requestBody:

```
        Dim cl = New ElktestService.CrsPortTypeClient("Test")
        Dim consumer, producer, userid, id, service As String
        consumer = "consumername"
        producer = "producername"
        userid = "user 1"
        id = "123456789"
        service = "producername.GetCommunityPeopleIds.v1"

        'Set token in header
        Dim hdr As New communityPeopleIdsRequestRequestHeader
        hdr.token = tempToken

        'Set dates í body
        Dim bdy As New communityPeopleIdsRequestRequestBody
        bdy.ModifiedSince = dtFromDate.Value
        bdy.ModifiedBefore = dtToDate.Value

        'set header & body into the request
        Dim req = New communityPeopleIdsRequest
        req.requestHeader = hdr
        req.requestBody = bdy

        'Set request property of the getCommunityPeopleIds
        Dim ppid = New GetCommunityPeopleIds()
        ppid.request = req

        'Now let's try to deserialze the xml that I send, so I can see what is being passed
        Dim serxml As System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(ElktestClient.ElktestService.communityPeopleIdsRequest))
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        serxml.Serialize(ms, req)
        Dim xml As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())

        Dim rsp = cl.GetCommunityPeopleIds(consumer, producer, userid, id, service, ppid)

        If rsp.faultCode Is Nothing And rsp.faultString Is Nothing Then
            For Each itm In rsp.response.PeopleIds
                Me.lstIds.Items.Add(itm.PublicId)
            Next
        End If
```

...and here is what the deserialized xml tells me I am sending (requestBody is empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<communityPeopleIdsRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <requestBody />
  <requestHeader>
    <token>FedAuth=7uPD........2lvbj0i+; path=/Crs/; secure; HttpOnly</token>
  </requestHeader>
</communityPeopleIdsRequest>
```

I have also checked with breakpoints, that just before the deserialization code, the content of the dates parameters are indeed set to correct values at runtime.

What is the obvious thing that I am missing - why are the dates not set and why is the requestBody empty? Any ideas on things to check?

Comment: req.requestBody should be set to a string.  You have it set to 'bdy' which is the type communityPeopleIdsRequestRequestBody.  I'm not sure it is a string or an object.  I think you want req.requestBody = xml where xml is your serialized object as a string.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng - but the req.requestBody is of the correct type, as the deserialization that I'm doing, is only to inspect the xml that is sent to the webservice (I'm not sending a string as the requestBody, but the actual object - problem is that the dates I set in its properties are not sent with the body object). ![image](http://i.imgur.com/NMgOYe6.png).